# R create subfolder with date and version number if not already present and increment version number if present

Tags: r

I am currently writing a piece of code that I will use to create a subfolder with the current date and version number on it (i.e. 20210603.0). If the folder is already present, I need to increment the version number until it reaches a subfolder of the current date and version combination that is not already existent (i.e. if 20210603.0 and 20210603.1 is already existent then I need to create a subfolder "20210603.2). I have the following code written out already, but I'm not certain how to loop through and create a new subfolder by incrementing the version number if a version (or versions) for the current date is already present. How can I write this second portion?

```
main_dir<-"some_path"
sub_dir<-paste0(format(Sys.time(),'%Y%m%d.'), 0)

if (!dir.exists(file.path(main_dir, sub_dir))) {
  dir.create(file.path(main_dir, sub_dir))
} else {
#code to increment version number until a date/version number combination is found to not 
#exist and then create folder labeled with the date/version number combination
}
```

Comment: One option would be to use `format(Sys.time(),'%Y%m%d.%H%M')` so you don't have to worry about the .1, .2 portion. Time/date will always be different unless you are saving these more than once per minute, in which case include seconds.

Comment: @Baroque This is quite helpful and would simplify my code a lot. I'll go this route! Thanks!